# なのに and んだけど in the same sentence

Tags: usage

If なのに already shows contradiction, what's the purpose of 'んだけど'?
Would be possible? Example:
 変顔なのに可愛いんだけど

Answer (score 3):

> 「変顔{へんがお}**なのに**可愛{かわい}いんだ**けど**。」 ("S/He's got a funny face, but s/he is cute....")

is a ***perfectly*** natural-sounding (and informal) sentence.  How could it be?

「けど」, when used ***mid-sentence***, is a contradictory conjunction as you seem to have already learned.

When 「けど」 is used at the ***end of a sentence*** as a sentence-ending particle, however, it is a whole different story.  ***It is used to beat around the bush by not expressing oneself clearly***.

To discuss what was left unsaid would be difficult without more context and/or a background story, but it would be something along the lines of 「なんでだろう」 ("why would that be?")、「変{へん}だよね」 ("It's so weird"), etc.

See definition #4 in [大辞林](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%91%E3%82%8C%E3%81%A9%E3%82%82-491210#E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E6.9E.97.20.E7.AC.AC.E4.B8.89.E7.89.88) where it says:

> ④  はっきり言{い}わず、遠回{とおまわ}しに述{の}べる気持{きも}ちを表{あらわ}す。

That means what I said above about beating around the bush.